# Crystal Reports Crosstab Layout - columns heading Not displyaing

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crosstab

i created a crosstab report using Crystal report,
but in my report Columns heading displays only Fist page, when i go to Next page there no column heading, please Help,

**Columns heading must repeat vertically**

first page of report-

2nd page of report

Comment: Normally crosstab should display... but tell me from where columns headings are coming? are those user defined or from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put them in the Page Header Section, not in Report Header. (if I get your question)

Comment: that cross tab cannot move or recreate in Report Header

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to Report Properties and Check the Report Header Reported on Every Page

Comment: how, could you please tell me the path